# Pickle ImportError: No module named __builtin__

Tags: python, module, importerror

I'm trying to load a (copied) pickle object in python3.6 and I get an Import Error for `__builtin__\r` when I do so.

```
with open('FilePath/FileName.pkl', "rb") as file:
    file = pickle.load(file)
```

> ```
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
> ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-36-b39fbab9bab4> in <module>()
>       1 with open('FilePath/FileName.pkl', "rb") as file:
> ----> 2     file = pickle.load(file)
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__builtin__\r'
> ```

When I try the same in python 2.7, I get an Import Error again, for `__builtin__` module:

> ```
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
>
> ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-3-12ac6524bf1a> in <module>()
>       1 with open('FilePath/FileName.pkl', "rb") as file:
> ----> 2     file = pickle.load(file)
>
> /Users/manasa.bulusu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/pickle.pyc in load(file)
>    1382 
>    1383 def load(file):
> -> 1384     return Unpickler(file).load()
>    1385 
>    1386 def loads(str):
>
> /Users/manasa.bulusu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/pickle.pyc in load(self)
>     862             while 1:
>     863                 key = read(1)
> --> 864                 dispatch[key](self)
>     865         except _Stop, stopinst:
>     866             return stopinst.value
>
> /Users/manasa.bulusu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/pickle.pyc in load_global(self)
>    1094         module = self.readline()[:-1]
>    1095         name = self.readline()[:-1]
> -> 1096         klass = self.find_class(module, name)
>    1097         self.append(klass)
>    1098     dispatch[GLOBAL] = load_global
>
> /Users/manasa.bulusu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/pickle.pyc in find_class(self, module, name)
>    1128     def find_class(self, module, name):
>    1129         # Subclasses may override this
> -> 1130         __import__(module)
>    1131         mod = sys.modules[module]
>    1132         klass = getattr(mod, name)
>
> ImportError: No module named __builtin__
> ```

I imported `builtins` (py3.6) and `__builtin__` (py2.7), but that didn't stop from throwing the exact same errors. 
What is the actual problem here? Also, `__builtin__\r` doesn't even seem like a real package in py36.

Comment: It looks like you may have written the pickle in text mode when you should have used binary mode.

Comment: @user2357112 Thanks for the response. Can you point to me what part of the error tells you that?

Comment: Unexpected `\r`s are frequently from the `\n`->`\r\n` conversion that happens in text mode on Windows.

Comment: @user2357112 Hmm.. interesting to know. This pickle file was written on a windows machine, but I'm using a Mac to load it now. Could that be a reason for this problem?

Comment: That definitely sounds like a text mode problem. You could try to replace `'\r\n'` with `'\n'` in the input and hope that fixes things, but it's not a good long-term plan; it's best to avoid generating pickle files with this problem in the first place.

Comment: @user2357112 I just tried to load this file on a Windows machine, and that didn't work either. It throws an `ImportError: No module named __builtin__` like the py2.7 error. What are your thoughts on that?

Comment: Strange - `fix_imports=True` (the default) is supposed to adjust that. Did you open the file in text mode or binary mode on Windows? Python 2 or Python 3?

Comment: @user2357112 I tried binary mode. Interestingly, just now, when I opened the file in text mode on Windows, it worked.

Comment: Oh, wait, the error message formatting is different. It's probably still got that `\r` on it, just invisible. Open it in text mode on Windows with Python 2, and you should be able to load it.

Comment: @user2357112 Thanks a lot. So, the problem is writing it on Windows and trying to load it using Mac. Is there a solution to bypass this problem? Will rewriting the file on Windows in binary mode help access it in binary mode using Mac?

Comment: Loading the data and repickling it in binary mode should fix the compatibility issue.

Comment: @user2357112 Thanks. If you could gather your suggestions into an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like you wrote the pickle in text mode on Windows (and on Python 2). Using text mode is a bad idea, because the `\n`->`\r\n` conversion makes such pickles unreadable on non-Windows, or on Python 3.

Reading the data in binary mode and calling `.replace(b'\r\n', b'\n')` before `loads`ing it would probably allow you to load the data, as would reloading the data on Windows on Python 2 and repickling it in binary mode.