# Error: No module named __builtin__ Reading .pkl

Tags: python, windows, runtime-error, pickle, built-in

I´m trying to read a pickle file on Windows in Python 3.9 and I have this error:

```py
import pickle

with open('FilePath/FileName.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    data = pickle.load(f)
```

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__builtin__'
```

I founded this solution [Pickle ImportError: No module named __builtin__](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46350566/pickle-importerror-no-module-named-builtin)

But I don't know how to replace the characters before loading the file.

Answer (score 0):

From your link:

> Reading the data in binary mode and calling `.replace(b'\r\n', b'\n')`
> before `loads`ing it would probably allow you to load the dat…

```
import pickle

with open('FilePath/FileName.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    ffff = f.read().replace(b'\r\n', b'\n') # Reading the data in binary mode and calling .replace
    data = pickle.loads(ffff)               # loads
```